# this is code for Rearrange array in alternating positive & negative items with O(1) extra space can you please explain what is & 0x01 elaborately?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, data-structures, hex

// this is code for Rearrange array in alternating positive & negative items with O(1) extra space can you please explain what is & 0x01 elaborately?

```
void rearrange(int arr[], int n) 
{
    int outofplace = -1;

    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) 
    {
        if (outofplace >= 0) 
        {
            // find the item which must be moved into the out-of-place
            // entry if out-of-place entry is positive and current
            // entry is negative OR if out-of-place entry is negative
            // and current entry is negative then right rotate
            //
            // [...-3, -4, -5, 6...] -->   [...6, -3, -4, -5...]
            //      ^                          ^
            //      |                          |
            //     outofplace      -->      outofplace
            //
            if (((arr[index] >= 0) && (arr[outofplace] < 0))
                    || ((arr[index] < 0) && (arr[outofplace] >= 0))) 
            {
                rightrotate(arr, n, outofplace, index);

                // the new out-of-place entry is now 2 steps ahead
                if (index - outofplace > 2) 
                    outofplace = outofplace + 2;
                else
                    outofplace = -1;
            }
        }

        // if no entry has been flagged out-of-place
        if (outofplace == -1) 
        {
            // check if current entry is out-of-place
            if (((arr[index] >= 0) && ((index & 0x01)==0))
                    || ((arr[index] < 0) && (index & 0x01)==1))**can someone explain what is happening here? what is & 0x01?**
                outofplace = index;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

> what is & 0x01 in regards to this problem?

Comment: can u please explain in regarding to this problem?

Comment: `index & 0x01` will return 1 if `index` is odd, and 0 if `index` is even. It has the same effect as `index % 2`.